# Text Mesh In Unity hides before the sprite after some Height.How to fix that?

Tags: unity-game-engine, text, sprite

I'm creating a baloon with some Random Alphabet (from A to Z) using Text Mesh and text Mesh is child of Baloon. But the problem I'm facing is that Text Mesh is visible for a few height after it gains height, it becomes invisible. Tested on Scene View, it seems that TextMesh gets before the Sprite. Even if text Mesh has a closer Z-axis value to camera than sprite.
How to fix that?

[Screen Shot For Text Hidden After Some Height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3VD2.png)

[Screen Shot For Text Visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppCzp.png)

Comment: I've already tweaked Far values.. No solution.

Answer (score 0):

This probably has something to do with how far your camera can see.

From both pictures you provided it looks like the object is farther away.

I dont have Unity in front of me, but adjust this setting inside the inspector for your camera.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-farClipPlane.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's true that I've set Far value of my Camera to 50(for performance), but I can't understand why it only bypasses TextMesh, if "Far" is the issue, it should not also see Sprite of Baloon????

Comment: Good point. You only have a single camera? Once I get in front of Unity I will see if I can replicate this. My initial thought was clipping because I face this same issue pretty often when dealing with UI.

Comment: Yeah... I'm using Single Cam